# How can I create vendor bundles for each dynamically imported module?

Tags: javascript, webpack-4, code-splitting, dynamic-import

I'm working on a CMS-based website with multiple separate pages, and I'm loading site-wide functionality onto every page using an `app.js` file loaded after a `vendor.js` file using the usual [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting) strategy. `app.js` is the main entry file, and it uses [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) to load page-specific scripts. Here's an example from my `app.js`:

```
/**
 * "Register for a class" page
 */
if (document.body.classList.contains("page-id-4136")) {
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "register-for-a-class" */ './pages/register-for-a-class/main')
}
```

In this case, the 'pages/register-for-a-class/main.js' file page uses [Vue](https://vuejs.org) as a dependency, but is the only page on the site so far to require it. I'd rather not bundle Vue into `vendor.js` when it's only being used on this page. I've tried to include Vue itself as a dynamic import by trying the following:

```
// pages/register-for-a-class/main.js

import(/* webpackChunkName: "vue" */ 'vue').then(({ default: Vue }) => {
  new Vue({
    ...
  })
})
```

But that gives me an error in webpack bundling that says `Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level`. So I also tried this:

```
// app.js

/**
 * "Register for a class" page
 */
if (document.body.classList.contains("page-id-4136")) {
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "vue" */ 'vue').then(({ default: Vue }) => {
        import(/* webpackChunkName: "register-for-a-class" */ './pages/register-for-a-class/main')
    })
}
```

That just flat out doesn't change anything. No "vue.bundle.js" file is created, and, naturally, loading the page creates a `Vue is not defined` error.

**So here's what I'm really asking.** What would be absolutely fantastic is if I could automatically have the `pages/register-for-a-class/main.js` just call a normal static import (e.g. `import Vue from 'vue'`) and have webpack generate both the `register-for-a-class.bundle.js` file and a corresponding `register-for-a-class-vendor.bundle.js` and dynamically import that vendor bundle automatically. It that possible?

Here is my current webpack.common.js file (I'm using [webpack-merge](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#setup)):

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './assets/src/app.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/src')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg)$/,
                use: ['url-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendor',
                    chunks: 'all'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery'
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend below approach of splitting. Hope this helps :)

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor1: ['vendor1', 'vendor2', 'vendor 3'], // all other vendor lists, package.json dependencies 
        vendor2: ['vue'],
        app: './assets/src/app.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/src')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg)$/,
                use: ['url-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor1: {
                    name: 'vendor1',
                    test: 'vendor1',
                    enforce: true
                },
                vendor2: {
                    name: 'vendor2',
                    test: 'vendor2',
                    enforce: true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery'
    },
    plugins: [new VueLoaderPlugin()]
};
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this would require me to modify the webpack configuration every time I add a new package. I'd really rather not do that, but thank you at least for giving an answer!

Comment: Not really. No need to modify webpack config. I have mentioned in comments to import package.json and provide the dependencies. No need to update webpack config afterwards.

Comment: I'm afraid that from your explanation I don't understand how to make your solution work.

Comment: did you a chance to try the solution ?

Comment: I think either you misunderstood my question or I misunderstand your suggested solution. Thank you anyway.